# C# Chromedriver options in whole program

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, csharpcodeprovider

Refer to the following code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{          
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    //this not working 
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

    // but this is working
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();  
  
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Is there a way to use ChromeOptions in whole program instead of writing it each time?

Comment: Might want to look at how to initialize private variables in a class.

Comment: Please include the compiler error in your question.